# find a set of values in a python dictionary based on its name

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

My JSON file has the following structure:

```
{ 
  "sets": 
          [ { "Name": "set1",  "Values": [ "value11", "value12" ] },
            { "Name": "set2",  "Values": [ "value21", "value22" ] } 
          ] 
}
```

The names are more meaningful than that, and there is more in the JSON. It is read by the `json` package into a dictionary, and my python script at some point needs the values from either `set1` or `set2`.

There are more than 2 sets in reality, and to find the right set to use, I now use this for-loop:

```
for s in protocol_data [ "sets" ]:
    if ( s [ "Name" ] == "set2" ):
       # do stuff with "Values"
```

So every time another set is needed, the whole array of sets needs to be traversed, which somehow does not feel like it's the way `dict` was intended. Could there be a cleverer way (maybe with a different container than `dict`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about preparing the data once. This trades off memory for runtime if you access the data multiple times.

```py
protocol_data_sets = {s['Name']: s['Values'] for s in protocol_data['sets']}
```

Then you can access all sets via `protocol_data_sets['the set you need']`

Comment: *that* is how dictionaries were intended. thanks! hope this was not too much of an open door...